# Implementing the binary search function using recursion

Tags: python, search

I'm trying to write a binary search function recursively without the use of slicing for my homework, but when I run my unit tests I get an error saying my function is not actually performing a binary search.

Here is my code. I was given def binarySearchRec(alist, item, first=None, last=None) so I have to use those 4 parameters with the default first and last values set to none.

```
def binarySearchRec(alist, item, first=None, last=None):
    if first == None and last == None:
        return binarySearchRec(alist, item, 0, len(alist) - 1)
    elif item < alist[first] or item > alist[last]:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if item < alist[midpoint]:
            return binarySearchRec(alist, item, first, midpoint - 1)
        elif item > alist[midpoint]:
            return binarySearchRec(alist, item, midpoint + 1, last)
        else:
            return True
```

Now when I run the unit tests, I get an error saying:

```
FAIL: test_ensureBinarySearch (__main__.TestProblem2)
P2: Is binarySearchRec actually performing a binary search?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Shared/Homework4/hw4_test.py", line 23, in test
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Shared/Homework4/hw4_test.py", line 193, in 
test_ensureBinarySearch
    self.assertLess(items.accesses, 20, "Binary search should only be 
testing log_2(N) items in a list with N items")
AssertionError: 32 not less than 20 : Binary search should only be testing 
log_2(N) items in a list with N items
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the number of accesses? Not exactly sure what "accesses" means. Can someone review my code and tell me what I did wrong? Thanks!

Here is the code for the unit test where I failed:

```
 def test_ensureBinarySearch(self):
        '''P2: Is binarySearchRec actually performing a binary search?'''
        items = StrictList(range(512))
        self.assertTrue(binarySearchRec(items, 232), "Failed to find an element 
in the list")
        self.assertLess(items.accesses, 20, "Binary search should only be 
testing log_2(N) items in a list with N items")
```

Comment: can you provide what test cases are you using?

Comment: Is your test-case counting *all* list accesses? In that case you are doing up to 4 per recursive step: `alist[first]`, `alist[last]`, and `alist[midpoint` x2.

Comment: you can check [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-binary-search/) too

Answer (score 0):

In *every* loop you are accessing `items` (your `alist`) twice to check if `elif item < alist[first] or item > alist[last]:`. You also are checking `items[midpoint]` twice if `item` Is not < `alist[midpoint]`.

<s>You can drop checking `elif item < alist[first] or item > alist[last]:` and just test if `first` or `last` run beyond the limits.</s> **Update:** *You could also use a temp value `mid_value = alist[midpoint]` to reduce the number of accesses to `alist[midpoint]`.*

You can drop the `elif item > alist[midpoint]:` and the third block. Only a single `else` will work fine.

It won’t have the optimizations you included, but will cut down on the number of access to `items`.

Lastly, if first and last are `None` simply set to the correct value and continue. No need to re call function.

Comment: How would I test if first or last run beyond the limits? Don't I have to know the value of the index to see if item is less than the value of first or greater than value of last?

Also if I only leave if item < alist[midpoint] then how would check if item == alist[midpoint]?

Comment: @John if item is less than `alist[0]` or greater than `alist[-1]`, eventually `first == last`, so `return False`

Comment: @John I've updated response. Leaving the if/elif/else works fine. Instead use temp variable to access `alist[midpoint]` once